# Replication advice for local SQL Server to hosted server

Tags: sql-server, hosting, replication, odata

we're close to migrating our legacy MS Access app to SQL Server for our internal warehouse management system. Our customers are often asking us for access to the data for e-commerce integration and general reporting. Once the migration is complete I would like to provide open access to the data via web services and odata. However I don't want to host these services as we are on a slow ADSL connection which won't cope with the traffic.

My question is, can I replicate (one-way) to a remote DB hosted by shared-hosting companies such as Hostgator? I see they have shared windows hosting with unlimited MS SQL DBs. Are there any special requirements on the hosted-side? For instance do I need to explicitly set-up replication on hosting db or is it managed on the client-side?

If this is possible then I might be able to run all our web services and reporting apps on the host's servers, and only the replicated data need travel over WAN. What sort of control is there over replication? Such as bandwidth throttling, replication periods etc? For instance when & how often does replication take place?

I'm new to SQL Server in general and some of the topics are a little overwhelming.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question is inappropriate for StackOverflow. It's a request for discussion and vendor specific information, and [SO isn't a discussion board or recommendation engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128550/172661). Voting to close as "not constructive". You'll have to ask the vendors you're considering these questions; they're specific to that hosting service.

Comment: OK perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned a specific hosting provider. I just wanted to know generally speaking, if providers offer an sql server instance whether or not it can be used for replication purposes. I appreciate that each and every one does things differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting up transactional replication with a [push subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152566.aspx) with the distributor on your side. The relevant bit is how the distribution agent connects to the subscriber. distrib.exe supports both trusted and SQL authentication, so you should be good to go either way.